# Method Returning Type Ignored

Tags: java

I am trying to get this method I made return the value of x*y as a long. However, it is returning a int. As far as I know specifying in the method header to return a long is what need to be done ?

I am unable to get the required result, what am I missing?

**Code**

```
public class Returnpower 
{

    public long power(int x,int n) 
    {   
        int total = x * n;
        if(x < 0 && n < 0)
        {
            System.out.println("X and/or N are not positive");
            System.exit(0);
        }
        return (total);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Returnpower power = new Returnpower();

        System.out.println(power.power(99999999,999999999));
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
469325057
```

Thanks

Ben

Comment: `int` * `int` = `int`, you need to do a cast to `long` at least to one of them and then apply the operation.

Comment: Well you use ints as params and in the function

Comment: I tried long total = x * n; and that gave me the same result but long total = x * (long)n; worked why is this ?

Comment: `x * (long)n` is explicitely converting the `n` as a long. It should create a copy of `n` as long. It also should create a copy of `x` as long because it will implicitely convert both operand to the bigger value in this case. We would have big problems if it was converting a big value implicitely to a smaller one. The same thing happen with `float` and `double`.

Comment: yer, that makes sense I learnt this but wasn't using it in my reasoning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's returning a `long`. It's just that you're performing the *arithmetic* in 32-bit integer arithmetic first. Look at how you're doing the arithmetic:

```
int total = x * n;
```

You're not even *storing* the result as a `long`, so I don't see how you could expect it to retain a full `long` value. You need `total` to be a `long` - *and* you've got to make one of the operands a `long` in order to make the multiplication occur in 64-bit.

To force the multiplication to occur in 64-bit arithmetic, you should cast one of the operands:

```
long total = x * (long) n;
```

Alternatively, just get rid of the `total` variable completely - I would suggest performing argument validation *before* using the parameters anyway:

```
public long power(int x, int n) 
{   
    if (x < 0 && n < 0)
    {
        // Use exceptions to report errors, not System.exit
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("x and/or n are negative");
    }
    return x * (long) n;
}
```

(Additionally, this clearly *isn't* performing a power operation in the same way as `Math.pow`, for example...)

Comment: wouldn't it be easier to change params to long? and the total variable

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix: Maybe, but that may not be an option. (For example, it might be implementing an interface in the real code.) Also note that multiplication for two `int`-size values in `long` arithmetic won't overflow, which might be a nice property to know...

Comment: Ah right, makes sense for interfaces, and it make sure we cannot have a `x * y` bigger than long.

Comment: @Loic the params need to be ints, anywho I tried long total = x * )n; at first not really thinking it threw. I forgot about the whole casting thing. thanks jon

Answer (score 1):

Change `int` to `long`

```
    public long power(int x,int n) 
    {
    long xx=x;
    long nn=n;
    long total = xx * nn;
    if(x < 0 && n < 0)
    {
        System.out.println("X and/or N are not positive");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    return total;
    }
```

Out put

```
99999998900000001
```